Copy certain value from Gsheet tab A to Gsheet tab B if two conditions are compl
I need your help as I'm in front of an excel / Gsheet question that I simply can't answer and also googling didn't help a lot.
At the moment I have a table that looks like this:



idCompany
MM-YYYY
open amount




123
01-2024
10.00


123
02-2024
25.00


456
01-2024
05.00


789
03-2024
15.50



In a new tab I now want to have one row per idCompany, where the open amount gets inserted automatically in the correct column. So my end goal should look like this:



idCompany
01-2024
02-2024
03-2024




123
10.00
25.00
NULL


456
05.00
NULL
NULL


789
NULL
NULL
15.50



I already tried it with VLOOKUP and CHOOSE but that didn't help (error: "VLOOKUP" leads to a value outside the valid range.) and several if conditions...
If there's an Excel pro out there (or maybe even a Gsheet one as I'm currently dealing with this on a Gsheet) I'd be more then happy.
Thanks in advance!

You can try this formula:
=QUERY(A1:C5,"SELECT Col1,MAX(Col3) GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2",1)


If you want to replace the blanks with nulls:
=ArrayFormula(LET(data,A1:C5,
                  summary,QUERY(data,"SELECT Col1,MAX(Col3) GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2",1),
                  final,IF(summary<>"",summary,"NULL"),
                  final))



Thanks a lot! I tried but I aways end up in the error "Error when parsing the formula." I checked for different datatypes but all seems fine.
As I'm not 100% familiar with formulas just for my understanding:
the first part refers to: "Check within this data fields" [QUERY (A1:C5)]
the 2nd part refers to: "Choose first column and throw value from column 3? [Col1,MAX(Col3)]
3rd part refers to: cluster everything by coloumn 1 [GROUP BY Col1 ]
4th part: I'm acutally lost on the PIVOT  [PIVOT Col2",]
5th part: also lost when it comes to this part [1]
Thanks for jumping in!

@ClaudiaM, yes, you can look at it that way. A1:C5 is the data set with headers that we're going to process. For SELECT, we want to return the idCompany (Col1),  but we need to cluster it vertically using GROUP BY. We use the PIVOT clause to cluster the Dates (Col2) horizontally in an ascending order. If we're aggregating (or clustering) the idCompany vs. Dates, we also need to provide an aggregated value (Open Amount) to complete the relationship between the two. My assumption is that there are no idCompany-Date duplicates.

Therefore, we can use the MAX Function inside the query to aggregate the Open Amount (Col3). If there are duplicates and you want to sum the values instead, then you can use SELECT SUM(Col3). This completes the SELECT Clause.  For the last argument, 1 means that the first row in A1:C5 is the header row.

I am not familiar with Google Sheets but I would use this same formula which works with Excel Version MS365 the only difference I wrap the output within an ARRAYFORMULA(), someone who is familiar and uses Google Sheets on regular may provide better solution, however, here is what I have tried using MAKEARRAY() function:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:C5,
     _Id, INDEX(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Id),
     _Date, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _UniqD, TOROW(UNIQUE(_Date)),
     ARRAYFORMULA(HSTACK(VSTACK(A1,_Uniq), VSTACK(_UniqD, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq), COLUMNS(_UniqD), LAMBDA(_r,_c, IFERROR(CHOOSEROWS(INDEX(_Data,,3),XMATCH(1,(INDEX(_Uniq,_r)=_Id)*(_Date=INDEX(_UniqD,_c)))),"NULL")))))))


In Excel Version --> MS365 it will be:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:C5,
     _Id, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Id),
     _Date, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _UniqD, TOROW(UNIQUE(_Date)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK(A1,_Uniq), VSTACK(_UniqD, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq), COLUMNS(_UniqD), LAMBDA(r,c, IFNA(CHOOSEROWS(TAKE(_Data,,-1),XMATCH(1,(INDEX(_Uniq,r)=_Id)*(_Date=INDEX(_UniqD,c)))),"NULL"))))))


If in the other sheets the ids and dates are already outlined then it could be using only XLOOKUP()
In Excel:
=XLOOKUP(1,($E2=$A$2:$A$5)*(F$1=$B$2:$B$5),$C$2:$C$5,"NULL")


In Google Sheets:
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(1,($E2=$A$2:$A$5)*(F$1=$B$2:$B$5),$C$2:$C$5,"NULL"))


Note: Please change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.


Thanks to the help of @vk26 (also kudos to @Mayukh Bhattacharya) I made this work. It was a stupid mistake from my end but at the end I simply had to replace the "," (comma) to ";" (semikolons) and it worked. So my formula was:

=QUERY(A1:C5;"SELECT Col1,MAX(Col3) GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2";1)

Love this community, really appreciate your help! 
